# How do you set read-only in NFS without root privilege on Linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, chmod, chown

This seems like a relatively straightforward question, but I couldn't really find an answer to this on knowledge bases.

**Problem**

I want to protect some files so they cannot be edited, deleted by other users, or at least not without writing an explicit command which removes this protection.
I want to perform this on a remote computer. Its output to cat /proc/version is

```
Linux version 2.6.32-754.33.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-031.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 10:29:45 EDT 2020
```

The file system should be NFS but I'm unsure (see comments below),

I confirmed that I cannot do chattr. Furthermore, I don't have root access, so I cannot set the files to read-only by chmod.

Is there anyway I could make a file read only?

As a proof of concept, I would like to do this for a txt file first, but I want to apply this "protection" to a couple of folders.

Comment: It has been a while but from memory, NFS is not actually a file-system but a network protocol to access a file-system, the the NDF volume could be EXT4 (or JFS or XFS or pretty much anything) so I would try to just `chmod a-w` the files you want to protect.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check whether the file system is EXT4 or not. However, I don't have root access (as above) and chattr doesn't work (chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on).

Comment: The point is that the underlying FS does not matter because you are talking to the interface of NFS. Try to lookup what is it's interface. As I said, haven't used NFS in a long time but it should support chmod.

Comment: It does support chmod, however, I don't have root access, as mentioned above.